# MySQL Connector C++ - Invalid Pointer

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I am trying to use the MySQL C++ Connector to connect to a database. I have added the libraries and the source code compiles correctly with all the necessary #include statements. The code I am using is the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    using namespace sql;

    Driver *driver;
    Connection *con;

driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver -> connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306/test", "test", "test");
}
```

The code is taken right from the examples and should work properly. I have shortened the code significantly, as it is at the final "driver -> connect" line where the error is thrown. My error message is the following:

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/username/NetBeansProjects/mysql/dist/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/mysql:
free(): invalid pointer: 0x091dd468 ***
```

I'm on Linux Mint Lisa, running the latest version of MySQL and using NetBeans 7.1 as an IDE. As mentioned, the code compiles correctly, and it is on this last connection line where the error occurs. Any help or recommendations for another connection mechanism would be much appreciated.

---

UPDATE

Here is the code from the Driver class where the connection is defined

```
class CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC Driver
{
protected:
virtual ~Driver() {}
public:
// Attempts to make a database connection to the given URL.

virtual Connection * connect(const sql::SQLString& hostName, const sql::SQLString& userName, const sql::SQLString& password) = 0;

virtual Connection * connect(ConnectOptionsMap & options) = 0;

...
```

Nothing to see there... in my humble opinion...

Comment: It looks as though some memory has been free'd and then attempted to be free'd again, but fails because it is no longer allocated. Cant really tell from the code you have posted, can you post the rest ? or put a link to the example code?

Comment: That is all the code! I will post the code from the page with the driver -> connect function, but that comes straight from the MySQL Connector development team so I doubt that it would contain an error :/.

Comment: Is `get_driver_instance` your code or is it part of Connector? If it's yours, post _that_.

Comment: Connector, but I can post it if you want. I haven't written any of the code here. I truncated a hello world program found on the MySQL website, and that is all. I found some information on the net about Boost library conflicts but that doesn't appear to apply to me here...

Comment: `get_driver_instance()` returns a pointer thus the value can be null which is something you **should** be checking for .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem for Ubuntu 12.04, it has taken me about 48 hours of no sleep but ok, here goes. Im sure this fix will work for other versions of Ubuntu.
Download the libstdc++.so.5 from http://www.sopcast.com/download/libstdcpp5.tgz. You need to extract and place the files in /usr/lib.

Make sure you add -llibstdc++.so.5 when building your app with g++ ( this links stdc++ v5)

Then Google 'Connector c++ Ubuntu 12.04' and look for the Builds and download the .deb for your Arch.

For Ubuntu 12.04 here is the URL for the .debs 
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/mysql-connector-c++/+builds
Choose your arch ie. Amd64 and download the two .debs under the Built Files. Open and install using the package manager. You should be able to run you app now without and issues.

**EDIT**
You do not need to link libstdc++.so.5, you might have to on your system but on Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 its not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Have your C++ programs talking to MySQL in under 2 minutes!

NOTE: this works on Ubuntu 12.04 servers (AWS EC2) with MySQL (typical LAMP setup), no backward compatibilty guaranteed.

To access MySQL databases from a C++ program, you must first install some mysql library files using the following command line

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

save a configuration file called "mysql_config" in the same directory where you will save (and run your app - let us say "/temp" )

```
mysql_config --cflags
-I/usr/include/mysql  -DBIG_JOINS=1  -fno-strict-aliasing   -DUNIV_LINUX
mysql_config --libs
-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient
```

compile your c++ file "myapp.cpp", with

```
sudo g++ -o myapp $(mysql_config --cflags) myapp.cpp $(mysql_config --libs)
```

based on [this excellent functional example](http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2010/02/17/mysql-connection-example/) written by [Coding Friends](http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/about-me/)

Comment: You've posted this very same answer four times now, we consider that a bit spammy. Please don't do this. If you are doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such. If they aren't exact dupes then just leave a comment under the question pointing to this answer. Thanks.

Comment: i apologize @Kev, the answer was appropriate for 4 questions.  what should i do?  leave these questions without a proper answer?  they are not exact duplicates, they are valid questions and my answer is valid for all of them.  i could answer pointing to an answer on another question, but nobody reads that.  AND, the previous answers available to these questions were quite frankly lame, IMHO.  BUT, since you make the rules, i will not do so again, lest i be called "spammy" again for trying to help others.  ps: am trying to alter the answers so as not to be "spammy", but cant find them, sorry.